# Converting strings in a nested loop to float

Tags: python, nested

Here is my code
I need to only convert the strings that are numbers to floats 
I have aList= lists of lists

```
    def convertData(aList):
       for items in aList:
          for x in items:
             try:
               float(x)
             except ValueError:
               pass
       print (aList)
```

This is what comes up for my list

```
   aList = [['Date', 'Assembly', 'Heat-treat', 'Painting', 'Inspection'], ['Monday',    '0.352', '0.92', '0.182', '0.255'], ['Tuesday', '0.438', '0.809', '0.155', '0.225'], ['Wednesday', '0.323', '0.9', '0.169', '0.236'], ['Thursday', '0.383', '0.841', '0.172', '0.238'], ['Friday', '0.355', '0.352', '0.177', '0.227']]
```

Comment: What's the problem? What is your expected output? and what did you get?

Comment: If you are not getting response from an answerer from your previous post the same question, then wait for it, rather than posting a duplicate of the question. Often you don't get response instantly.

Comment: @RohitJain I had that question I did not get a proper reply

Comment: @RohitJain can you take a look at my code then

Comment: Why do you want it all in one function? In your previous question you got the complete solution. Why can't you use it?

Answer (score 0):

```
def convertData(aList):
   for items in aList:
      for i,j in enumerate(items):
         try:
           items[i] = float(j)
         except ValueError:
           continue
   print (aList)
```

Comment: that seems to have taken out only the first item in my nested lists and still hasnt converted the numbers to floats

Comment: ooopsss. sorry. try now.

Answer (score 0):

```
def convertData(aList):
   lout = []
   for items in aList:
      itemsout = []
      for x in items:
         try:
           itemsout.append(float(x))
         except ValueError:
           itemsout.append(x)
      lout.append(itemsout)
   return lout
```